# Runtime libraries are not installed or copied

Tags: .net, .net-standard-2.0, chilkat

I have a netstandard 2.0 project that I am trying to add into it a reference to nuget `ChilkatDnStandard`. The `ChilkatDnStandard` library depends on `ChilkatNativeLib` which contains all the native libraries for various platforms.

This library mentioned above is then referenced in the same solution (project reference) by two projects: One is dotnet core 7, one is dotnet framework 4.8. When compiling these projects, the netstandrard project is copied, the `ChilkatDnStandard` library is copied but the runtimes folder that comes out of the `ChilkatNativeLib` is not copied over resulting in errors when trying to run these two projects.

If I add a reference to `ChilkatNativeLib` in the netstandard library then the runtimes are copied to the core 7 project but not to the net 4.8 project.

My netstandard project already contains `<CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>` (without it I saw that assemblies referenced by the netstandard library would not be copied to the core/framework projects)

Was I supposed to add to the netstandard project the `ChilkatNativeLib` library to begin with? why is the runtimes folder that `ChilkatNativeLib` creates is not being copied to the core/framework projects? I think I could add the `ChilkatNativeLib` reference to the core/framework projects so the runtimes get there but I am not sure that is the way it is supposed to work.

Answer (score 0):

It's not correct to reference the ChilkatDnStandard library from a .NET Framework 4.8 project.  For the .NET Framework 4.8 project, you should reference one of the following NuGet packages:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/chilkat-x64

or

https://www.nuget.org/packages/chilkat-win32

Comment: Also, to understand .NET Standard, ask ChatGPT "Explain .NET Standard 2.0 with respect to .NET Core and .NET Framework"

Comment: Maybe I didnt explain myself correctly so let me try to clarify: I am in the process of moving my framework code to core. but since it cannot be done at once I am currenly moving utilitiy functions that use Chilkat components to a netstandard project so that both the old code and the new one can use it (it will be converted to a core project at the end). The problem is that the framework project referencing the standards project does not get the runtime files copied to it

Answer (score 0):

".NET Standard 2.0 is a version of the .NET Standard specification, which is a set of APIs that define a common base for .NET platforms to implement." -- ChatGPT.

In other words, let's say
.NET Standard 2.0 is comprised of A, B, E, G.
.NET Core 7 is comprised of A, B, C, E, G, Z
.NET Framework 4.8 is comprised of A, B, D, G, Y

When you create project conforming to .NET Standard 2.0, you're saying: "I'm only using things in the .NET Standard 2.0 API" -- for example, A, B, E, and G.

Thus your source code can be used in either a .NET Core 7 or .NET Framework 4.8 project.

There is no such thing as a ".NET Standard 2.0" project.  It can be a .NET Core 7 project that restrains itself to using only things in the .NET Standard 2.0 API, or perhaps it is a .NET Framework 4.8 project that restrains itself to using only things in the .NET Standard 2.0 API.